# Ref is null while writing test in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have fully working source code but while writing a unit test have faced the issue, how I create the ref:

```
private JsonInputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> = React.createRef();
```

How I use it:

```
if (errorMessage == null) {
  if (this.JsonInputRef.current) {
    this.JsonInputRef.current.setCustomValidity('');
  }
  onValueChange && onValueChange(value, e);
} else {
  if (this.JsonInputRef.current) {
    this.JsonInputRef.current.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

and the issue, report from test coverage:

[image]

and where I call the ref:

```
render() {
// to exclude unknown property 'onValueChange' for JsonInput for DevTools
const { height = '', onValueChange, ...restProps } = this.props;
  return (
    <StyledTextArea
      ref={this.JsonInputRef}
      {...restProps}
      onChange={this.handleValueChange}
      height={height}
    />
  );
}
```

I conclude that `this.JsonRef.current` is `null` but how to test it or refactor properly to have full test coverage?

Comment: You probably need to explain, where this code is located (for instance, refs are not initialised on first render) and how you define this ref.

Comment: In your render you could do a `if (this.JsonInputRef!==null)`. Then your test will be executed after the ref is populated. Or you could use React's lifecycle to determine when JsonInputRef is populated but I cannot provide an example from the code you posted.